# Floating action button not working in marshmallow and lollipop

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, floating-action-button

I have `FloatingActionButton` in my app. It is working fine in Android N and O . but it is crashing in Marshmallow. Can any one help me to solve this issue.

**Error**

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at LibraryFragment.onCreateView(LibraryFragment.java:69)
```

XML

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabChat"
        android:backgroundTint="#114358"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/language"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4sp" />
```

build.gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {

            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: for test case **`app:elevation="4dp"`**

Comment: @NileshRathod still same issue

Comment: share your `build.gradle` with questoon

Comment: @NileshRathod see edited question

Comment: try yo **`clear-rebuild`** your project

Comment: already did so many times

Comment: for test case remove `android:backgroundTint="#114358"`

Comment: also try with `invalidate-cache and restart`

Comment: i also tried invalidate and restart still same issue

Comment: @drawable/language is vector file?

Comment: are you sure this is only one `FloatingActionButton` in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the version you are using with Android design library:

Paste this inside dependencies, if it is already there then replace it

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Also change compileSdkVersion to 25

Also change:
`android:backgroundTint="#114358"` with `app:backgroundTint="#114358"`

And if you are using vector asset as src then use

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/you_graphics"
```

Insted of this
 `android:src="@drawable/your_graphics"`

Hope it helps

Comment: can you post the dependencies part of your gradle?

Answer (score 1):

> This work  in marshmallow and lollipop

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingButtonCustomer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/refresh"
            android:layout_above="@+id/floatingButtonAdd"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/floatingButtonAdd"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

> Add bellow in App gradle file

```
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
```